# Dual Boot (MacOS/Linux)

Tags: linux, macos, boot, refit

I installed Ubuntu on dual boot on MacOS using rEFIt.

Then, when I did not expect it, the Linux System stoped working, I decided to reboot the computer with MacOS when, for my surprise, everything (included MacOS) was erased.

Why could this happen? How can I create correctly this dual boot on MacOS?

Comment: What version of rEFIt did you used? The original program [was discontinued](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) in 2013. However, there is a new fork of it called [rEFInd Boot Manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/). You may need to install GRUB because it seems a bootloader problem.

Comment: @CaldeiraG Thanks! Yes, I finally think it was a bootloader problem. Should I install GRUB on MacOS before installing rEFInd Boot Manager and Ubuntu? And with just GRUB would be solved the bootloader problem?